# How can I know that I have used Spark 3.2 External Shuffle Service

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, shuffle

I'm running wordcount with Spark 3.2 and I have deployed it as https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html#configuring-the-external-shuffle-service described.
The spark-xx-yarn-shuffle.jar is from  $SPARK_HOME/dev/make-distribution.sh,
so:
1）how can I know that I have use THIS jar （or ESS）?
2) Can I build this jar？